# Plotting live serial data from Arduino, plot doesn't update unless manually closed?

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino

I am using an Arduino with a temperature sensor and using python to save the data as csv. Specifically, the arduino is printing out 2 sets of values, one set to use as a measure of time (number increases by 1 every 10 seconds) and one set detailing the temperature reading. I have it set up that the arduino prints 10 values then waits 10 seconds. The python code then takes the average of the 10 readings. I want to plot both these values that updates in real time. I will add the code below. It works in principle, however, it will not update the figure after each measurement. I have to manually close the figure window before it will show the figure with the next plot. The measurements seem to keep running in the background, for example if I wait 60 seconds I will then have 6 graphs to open/close before it 'catches up' with the new data coming in. I am very new to python so forgive me if the answer is obvious.

```
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x_vals = []
y_vals= []
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
num_averages=10

filename = "E:/Python/Data/TemperatureReadPlotreadings.csv"

port = "COM3"
baudrate = 9600
arduino = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)

arduino.flush()

def readdata():
    dataline = arduino.readline()
    try:
        y = dataline.decode("ascii").strip().split(",")
        for i in range(len(y)):
            y[i] = float(y[i])    
        return y
    except ValueError:
        arduino.flush()
        y = [0,0]
        return y

def save_data(filename, mean, stddev):
    print("Saving data")
    
    datafile = open(filename, 'a')
    
    datafile.write("{0:6.2f}".format(mean[0])+ "," + "{0:6.3f}".format(stddev[0])+ "," + "{0:9.2f}".format(mean[1])+ "," + "{0:9.3f}".format(stddev[1])+ "\n")
   
    datafile.close()
def animate(i):
            x_vals.append(mean[0])
            y_vals.append(mean[1])
            
            plt.cla()
            plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, label = "LM35")
            
run = True
while run:
    try:  
        data = np.zeros((2,num_averages))
        mean = np.zeros(2)
        stddev = np.zeros(2)
        for i in range(num_averages):
            data_new = readdata()
            data[0,i] = data_new[0]
            data[1,i] = data_new[1] 

        for i in range(2):
            mean[i] = np.mean(data[i,:])
            stddev[i] = np.std(data[i,:])

        save_data(filename, mean, stddev)
        
        
        ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=10000)
    
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.draw()
        plt.show()

                                     
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print('\nExiting')
         run = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check out how the Animation classes work. `FuncAnimation()` is only called **once**. It will call `animate()` periodically.

See the example and explanations [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Also you don't need to clear and replot the whole thing in `animate()`. You only need to update the line ([Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D)) like `ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)`. `plt.plot()` is only called once and returns the [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) object.

I see you need to call `readdata()` periodically to get your data. You could do it in `animation()` but I would recommend you run it in a separate thread:

```
#import threading
.
.
.
yourDataReadingThread = threading.Thread(target=readdata)
yourDataReadingThread.start()
```

More on threading [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

This will run `readdata()` once. So inside `readdata()` you need a loop like you had one in your main thread, but this time it won't block your main thread. And inside this loop you could also append the new data to your `x_vals` and `y_vals` lists. This way the only thing you need to call in `animate()` is `ln.set_data(x_vals , y_vals )`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll have a play around and see if I can get it to work this way.